# how can prove $n^n$ is primitive recursive

Tags: logic, recursion, computability, recursive-algorithms

I try to prove $n^n$ is primitive recursive,first i try to releationate this proof with the proof of $x^y$, but in this case is different, because the base is not the same.

So my attempt was to see the relationship between $n^n$ and $(n + 1)^{(n+1)}$ by the newtons formula,an i got:
$
(n+1)^{(n+1)}=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n+1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) n^{n+1-k}
=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) n^{n+1 - k}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
n+1 \\
0 \end{array}\right) n(n)^{n}+ \left(\begin{array}{l}
n+1 \\
1 \end{array}\right)n^n
$
So i would think that I can express as a sum of $n ^ n$, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: If you know $f(x,y)=x^y$ is primitive recursive, can’t you just apply the composition axiom to get that $g(n)=f(n,n)$ is as well?

Comment: I know, but I wanted to see if I could show it without using $ x ^ y $

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First we know multiplication funtion is primitive recursive (multiplication is a doubly nested primitive recursions of the initial $S$-function), and also we know $f(n)=n^n=n \times (n \times(...n \times (n \times n))...))$ and the number of multiplication functions is fixed as $(n-1)$, so apparently $f(n)$ is a primitive recursion of multiplications. Since primitive recursion of p.r. functions is still p.r., so $f(n)=n^n$ is still primitive recursive. Note here for your example function we don't need any exponential function concept.

Comment: "the number of multiplication functions is fixed as $(n-1)$" .... No. $n$ is a variable, so $n \times (n \times(...n \times (n \times n))...))$ is not a closed formula, and thus not a straightforward composition of multiplications. You really need primitive recursion to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no simpler way to do this than effectively doing the proof for primitive recursion of $x^y$ ... but with $x$ and $y$ being the same. Or, do what Eric says in the Comments: now that you know that $f(x,y)=x^y$ is primitive recursive, simply note that $g(n)=f(n,n)$ is therefore primitive recursive as well.